# Make Webpart connections to work when a dropdown value is changed

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, jquery, data-view-web-part, connected-web-parts

I have a simple newform.aspx which has Employee as a textbox. During onload of the page, I assign this with currentuser.

On the same page, I have a webpart created using sharepoint designer that shows employee details within newform.aspx itself. I have used the employee value as a sender using webpart connections.

Recently I made a change that the employee can be anyone (including current user). So I made employee to be dropdown but onload I still assign current user. Now when we select another employee from dropdown the webpart connection doesn't work and it always shows current user employee details only.

Question is how do I make the webpart connection to refresh whenever there is a change in the dropdown.

If it can't be done without customization, please suggest how to proceed with customization.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to do it with the selectedindexchanged-event of the asp-dropdownlist? ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx ) I'm not sure if you're asking for this, so I just comment ;)

Comment: @Dominik: The dropdown is created by sharepoint in the newform.aspx. Newform.aspx is created by sharepoint and to write the event for dropdown change, I need to what changes are required to newform.aspx.